# Excel vlookup range issue while adding using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, formula

**1st VBA code**: I am using vlookup formula in VBA, below is the formula I placed in VBA:

```
Rng.Formula = "=IF(RC" & SeseCol & " ="""","""",IF(LEFT(LOWER(RC" & SeseCol & "),4)=""none"","""",VLOOKUP(LEFT(RC" & SeseCol & ",(FIND("" "",RC" & SeseCol & ",1)-1)),'[HMO Base Rule Picker - Formula.xlsm]BaseRule'!C[-10]:C[-5],2,0)))"
```

**1st VBA output**: From the above code I get the below formula in excel which is correct:

```
=IF($C17 ="","",IF(LEFT(LOWER($C17),4)="none","",VLOOKUP(LEFT($C17,(FIND(" ",$C17,1)-1)),BaseRule!B:G,2,0)))
```

**2nd VBA code**: However I wanted make C[-10]:C[-5] to a constant range and tried changing to $B:$G as below VBA code:

```
Rng.Formula = "=IF(RC" & SeseCol & " ="""","""",IF(LEFT(LOWER(RC" & SeseCol & "),4)=""none"","""",VLOOKUP(LEFT(RC" & SeseCol & ",(FIND("" "",RC" & SeseCol & ",1)-1)),'[HMO Base Rule Picker - Formula.xlsm]BaseRule'!$B:$G,2,0)))"
```

**2nd VBA output**: Then I am getting the below formula from the above code which is not working. I am not getting the same as 1st VBA output formula, am I missing something on the 2nd code?

```
=IF(RC7 ="","",IF(LEFT(LOWER(RC7),4)="none","",VLOOKUP(LEFT(RC7,(FIND(" ",RC7,1)-1)),BaseRule!$B:$G,2,0)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `C2:C7` instead in place of `C[-10]:C[-5]`.
Final formula would be:

```
Rng.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC" & SeseCol & " ="""","""",IF(LEFT(LOWER(RC" & SeseCol & _
    "),4)=""none"","""",VLOOKUP(LEFT(RC" & SeseCol & ",(FIND("" "",RC" & SeseCol & _
    ",1)-1)),'[HMO Base Rule Picker - Formula.xlsm]BaseRule'!C2:C7,2,0)))"
```

In R1C1 Notation `[]` brackets are used to indicate *relative* referencing.
To indicate absolute reference, you just need to indicate the actual *column* or *row* number. 
 So for *Column B* that is `C2` which is the 2nd column.
 For *Column G* which is the 7th column would be `C7`.

Also take note that I used `FormulaR1C1` property above.
That is the correct property when you're using the R1C1 notation in your formula.